# How to perform Find, Distinct & Sort all together using go mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, mongo-go

I have a command which is made using `"labix.org/v2/mgo"` library

```
err = getCollection.Find(bson.M{}).Sort("department").Distinct("department", &listedDepartment)
```

this is working fine. But now I'm moving to the official golang mongo-driver `"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"` and I want to run this command in that library but there is no direct function that I can use with Find then Sort then Distinct. How can I achieve this command using this mongo-driver. The variable `listedDepartment` is type of `[]string`. Please suggest me know the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`Collection.Distinct()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?tab=doc#Collection.Distinct) but it does not yet support sorting:

```
// Obtain collection:
c := client.Database("dbname").Collection("collname")

ctx := context.Background()
results, err := c.Distinct(ctx, "department", bson.M{})
```

It returns a value of type `[]interface{}`. If you know it contains `string` values, you may use a loop and type assertions to obtain the string values like this:

```
listedDepartment = make([]string, len(results))
for i, v := range results {
    listedDepartment[i] = v.(string)
}
```

And if you need it sorted, simply sort the slice:

```
sort.Strings(listedDepartment)
```